# Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error And WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80041002 Error: 0x80041002 (null)

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've downloaded Docker Desktop to run it, but when I open it, I get an error message: **Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error**:

```
`(Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error btrd.
An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command. Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.
Please try shutting WSL down (ws --shutdown) and/or rebooting your computer. If not Docker Engine sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue )`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwAlJ.jpg)
I've tried using **wsl --shutdown**, but it didn't work. After checking the Docker documentation, I found out that Docker requires WSL 2 and Hyper-V, so I updated to the latest version of WSL 2 and installed Hyper-V. However, Docker still doesn't work.
When I use the **wsl -l -v** command to list all installed Linux distributions in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I noticed that in WSL 1, I had Ubuntu version 1. Since Docker requires version 2, I used the wsl --set-default-version 2 command to switch to WSL 2. However, I couldn't see any Linux distributions listed, which I believe is causing the Docker issue.
I tried to switch Ubuntu to version 2 using the **wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2** command, but I encountered the error:

```
(Failed to configure network (networkingMode Nat). To disable networking, set wsl2.networkingMode=None in C:\Users\DELL\.wslconfig. Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/HNS/0x80041002.)
```

So, I decided to uninstall the current Ubuntu and reinstall a different one using **wsl --install -d Ubuntu**. However, I still encounter the same error.

```
    (WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80041002 Error: 0x80041002 (null))
```

I've also tried enabling **Hyper-V, Virtual Machine, and Windows Subsystem for Linux**, and I've enabled virtualization in the BIOS. I've tried various solutions from Google and YouTube, but none of them worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBeRA.jpg)

Windows 11 Home Single Language
WSL 2

Could someone please help me with this?